# libgdx throwing an exception on helloworld app when ran in emulator

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've followed the tutorial on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLx_72qxK_0&feature=player_embedded and created a simple app with the libgdx library that makes an application with a red background.

This works fine when I run it as a stand alone desktop app, but when I run the -android version the exception below is thrown and the application fails to start.

```
02-04 18:25:27.536: W/dalvikvm(456): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication;
02-04 18:25:27.536: W/dalvikvm(456): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lorg/gravity/main/GameAndroidActivity;)
02-04 18:25:27.567: D/AndroidRuntime(456): Shutting down VM
02-04 18:25:27.567: W/dalvikvm(456): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gdx: findLibrary returned null
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:111)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:58)
02-04 18:25:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  ... 15 more
```

Does anyone have any experience with this library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fixed the issue by making sure the armeabi and armeabi-v7a folders were in /libs of the android project.

Comment: You might be best asking in the libgdx irc channel as I got the solution that worked for me from them.

Comment: I got this error in Cocos 2d Android. I think Cocos is using Libgdx at back end. And now my problem is solved. I just use the backup I created for the project. It worked. Strange

Comment: @JawadAmjad I'm having the same problem with cocos2dx.  What did you do?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem was caused by trying to run on an android AVD with the intel atom x86 image. I believe you have to use an ARM image.

Answer (score 0):

Source: [How to import the x86 folders for android](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3103) (July 2013)

The developpers told us that they give the missing `x86` folder in the latest nightly so that you are not forced to use an ARM emulator.

So download the latest nightly below, and copy the `x86` folder to the `libs/` folder of your project/library project (where you will also find the `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` folders)

### [The latest nightly for libgdx containing the x86 folder to put in libs/](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/libgdx-nightly-latest.zip)

This solved the problem for me.